# Cascading WMTS from ArcGis Server in Geoserver 2.13.2 with proxy server

Tags: geoserver, arcgis-online, wmts

I am running geoserver 2.13.2, Apache Tomcat 9.0.7, Java 8 Update 171.  I create a WMTS store called test with a get capabilities set to a reference address of http://sampleserver6.arcgisonline.com/arcgis/rest/services/Toronto/ImageServer/WMTS/1.0.0/WMTSCapabilities.xml

I have a proxy server set in Java C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 9.0\bin\tomcat9w:

-Dhttp.proxySet=true

-Dhttp.proxyHost=proxyserver

-Dhttp.proxyPort=80

Using IE, store creation works, layer creation works.  When I come to perform a layer preview I get

[image: Image preview]

This is the GetCApabilities

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <Capabilities xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/wmts/1.0"
    xmlns:ows="http://www.opengis.net/ows/1.1"
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/wmts/1.0 http://schemas.opengis.net/wmts/1.0/wmtsGetCapabilities_response.xsd"
    version="1.0.0">
    <!-- Service Identification --> <ows:ServiceIdentification>
    <ows:Title>Toronto</ows:Title>
    <ows:ServiceType>OGC WMTS</ows:ServiceType>
    <ows:ServiceTypeVersion>1.0.0</ows:ServiceTypeVersion>
    </ows:ServiceIdentification> <!-- Operations Metadata --> <ows:OperationsMetadata>
    <ows:Operation name="GetCapabilities">
    <ows:DCP>
    <ows:HTTP>
    <ows:Get xlink:href="http://sampleserver6.arcgisonline.com/arcgis/rest/services/Toronto/ImageServer/WMTS/1.0.0/WMTSCapabilities.xml">
    <ows:Constraint name="GetEncoding">
    <ows:AllowedValues>
    <ows:Value>RESTful</ows:Value>
    </ows:AllowedValues>
    </ows:Constraint>
    </ows:Get>
    <!-- add KVP binding in 10.1 -->
    <ows:Get xlink:href="http://sampleserver6.arcgisonline.com/arcgis/rest/services/Toronto/ImageServer/WMTS?">
    <ows:Constraint name="GetEncoding">
    <ows:AllowedValues>
    <ows:Value>KVP</ows:Value>
    </ows:AllowedValues>
    </ows:Constraint>
    </ows:Get>
    </ows:HTTP>
    </ows:DCP>
    </ows:Operation>
    <ows:Operation name="GetTile">
    <ows:DCP>
    <ows:HTTP>
    <ows:Get xlink:href="http://sampleserver6.arcgisonline.com/arcgis/rest/services/Toronto/ImageServer/WMTS/tile/1.0.0/">
    <ows:Constraint name="GetEncoding">
    <ows:AllowedValues>
    <ows:Value>RESTful</ows:Value>
    </ows:AllowedValues>
    </ows:Constraint>
    </ows:Get>
    <ows:Get xlink:href="http://sampleserver6.arcgisonline.com/arcgis/rest/services/Toronto/ImageServer/WMTS?">
    <ows:Constraint name="GetEncoding">
    <ows:AllowedValues>
    <ows:Value>KVP</ows:Value>
    </ows:AllowedValues>
    </ows:Constraint>
    </ows:Get>
    </ows:HTTP>
    </ows:DCP>
    </ows:Operation>
    </ows:OperationsMetadata> <Contents>
    <!--Layer--> <Layer>
    <ows:Title>Toronto</ows:Title> <ows:Identifier>Toronto</ows:Identifier>
    <ows:BoundingBox crs="urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::3857">
    <ows:LowerCorner>-8844874.0651 5401062.402699997</ows:LowerCorner>
    <ows:UpperCorner>-8828990.0651 5420947.402699997</ows:UpperCorner>
    </ows:BoundingBox> <ows:WGS84BoundingBox crs="urn:ogc:def:crs:OGC:2:84">
    <ows:LowerCorner>-79.45485558791692 43.58252352397558</ows:LowerCorner>
    <ows:UpperCorner>-79.31216718818739 43.71178084047906</ows:UpperCorner>
    </ows:WGS84BoundingBox>
    <Style isDefault="true">
    <ows:Title>Default Style</ows:Title>
    <ows:Identifier>default</ows:Identifier>
    </Style>
    <Format>image/jpgpng</Format>
    <TileMatrixSetLink>
    <TileMatrixSet>default028mm</TileMatrixSet>
    </TileMatrixSetLink>
    <TileMatrixSetLink>
    <!--Only show this TileMatrixSet if the tiling scheme is compliant to Google Maps (and that happens with tile width = 256 px)-->
    <TileMatrixSet>GoogleMapsCompatible</TileMatrixSet>
    </TileMatrixSetLink>
    <ResourceURL format="image/jpgpng" resourceType="tile" template="http://sampleserver6.arcgisonline.com/arcgis/rest/services/Toronto/ImageServer/WMTS/tile/1.0.0/Toronto/{Style}/{TileMatrixSet}/{TileMatrix}/{TileRow}/{TileCol}" />
    </Layer> <!--TileMatrixSet-->
    <TileMatrixSet>
    <ows:Title>TileMatrix using 0.28mm</ows:Title>
    <ows:Abstract>The tile matrix set that has scale values calculated based on the dpi defined by OGC specification (dpi assumes 0.28mm as the physical distance of a pixel).</ows:Abstract> <ows:Identifier>default028mm</ows:Identifier>
    <ows:SupportedCRS>urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::3857</ows:SupportedCRS>
    <TileMatrix>
    <ows:Identifier>0</ows:Identifier>
    <ScaleDenominator>5.590822640285016E8</ScaleDenominator>
    <TopLeftCorner>-2.0037508342787E7 2.0037508342787E7</TopLeftCorner> <TileWidth>256</TileWidth> <TileHeight>256</TileHeight>
    <MatrixWidth>1</MatrixWidth> <MatrixHeight>1</MatrixHeight>
    </TileMatrix>
    <TileMatrix>
    <ows:Identifier>1</ows:Identifier>
    <ScaleDenominator>2.7954113201425034E8</ScaleDenominator>
    <TopLeftCorner>-2.0037508342787E7 2.0037508342787E7</TopLeftCorner> <TileWidth>256</TileWidth> <TileHeight>256</TileHeight>
    <MatrixWidth>1</MatrixWidth> <MatrixHeight>1</MatrixHeight>
    </TileMatrix>
    <TileMatrix>
    <ows:Identifier>2</ows:Identifier>
    <ScaleDenominator>1.3977056600712562E8</ScaleDenominator>
    <TopLeftCorner>-2.0037508342787E7 2.0037508342787E7</TopLeftCorner> <TileWidth>256</TileWidth> <TileHeight>256</TileHeight>
    <MatrixWidth>2</MatrixWidth> <MatrixHeight>2</MatrixHeight>
    </TileMatrix>
    <TileMatrix>
    <ows:Identifier>3</ows:Identifier>
    <ScaleDenominator>6.988528300356235E7</ScaleDenominator>
    <TopLeftCorner>-2.0037508342787E7 2.0037508342787E7</TopLeftCorner> <TileWidth>256</TileWidth> <TileHeight>256</TileHeight>
    <MatrixWidth>3</MatrixWidth> <MatrixHeight>3</MatrixHeight>
    </TileMatrix>
    <TileMatrix>
    <ows:Identifier>4</ows:Identifier>
    <ScaleDenominator>3.494264150178117E7</ScaleDenominator>
    <TopLeftCorner>-2.0037508342787E7 2.0037508342787E7</TopLeftCorner> <TileWidth>256</TileWidth> <TileHeight>256</TileHeight>
    <MatrixWidth>5</MatrixWidth> <MatrixHeight>6</MatrixHeight>
    </TileMatrix>
    <TileMatrix>
    <ows:Identifier>5</ows:Identifier>
    <ScaleDenominator>1.7471320750890587E7</ScaleDenominator>
    <TopLeftCorner>-2.0037508342787E7 2.0037508342787E7</TopLeftCorner> <TileWidth>256</TileWidth> <TileHeight>256</TileHeight>
    <MatrixWidth>9</MatrixWidth> <MatrixHeight>12</MatrixHeight>
    </TileMatrix>
    <TileMatrix>
    <ows:Identifier>6</ows:Identifier>
    <ScaleDenominator>8735660.375445293</ScaleDenominator>
    <TopLeftCorner>-2.0037508342787E7 2.0037508342787E7</TopLeftCorner> <TileWidth>256</TileWidth> <TileHeight>256</TileHeight>
    <MatrixWidth>18</MatrixWidth> <MatrixHeight>24</MatrixHeight>
    </TileMatrix>
    <TileMatrix>
    <ows:Identifier>7</ows:Identifier>
    <ScaleDenominator>4367830.187722647</ScaleDenominator>
    <TopLeftCorner>-2.0037508342787E7 2.0037508342787E7</TopLeftCorner> <TileWidth>256</TileWidth> <TileHeight>256</TileHeight>
    <MatrixWidth>36</MatrixWidth> <MatrixHeight>47</MatrixHeight>
    </TileMatrix>
    <TileMatrix>
    <ows:Identifier>8</ows:Identifier>
    <ScaleDenominator>2183915.0938617955</ScaleDenominator>
    <TopLeftCorner>-2.0037508342787E7 2.0037508342787E7</TopLeftCorner> <TileWidth>256</TileWidth> <TileHeight>256</TileHeight>
    <MatrixWidth>72</MatrixWidth> <MatrixHeight>94</MatrixHeight>
    </TileMatrix>
    <TileMatrix>
    <ows:Identifier>9</ows:Identifier>
    <ScaleDenominator>1091957.5469304253</ScaleDenominator>
    <TopLeftCorner>-2.0037508342787E7 2.0037508342787E7</TopLeftCorner> <TileWidth>256</TileWidth> <TileHeight>256</TileHeight>
    <MatrixWidth>144</MatrixWidth> <MatrixHeight>187</MatrixHeight>
    </TileMatrix>
    <TileMatrix>
    <ows:Identifier>10</ows:Identifier>
    <ScaleDenominator>545978.7734656851</ScaleDenominator>
    <TopLeftCorner>-2.0037508342787E7 2.0037508342787E7</TopLeftCorner> <TileWidth>256</TileWidth> <TileHeight>256</TileHeight>
    <MatrixWidth>287</MatrixWidth> <MatrixHeight>374</MatrixHeight>
    </TileMatrix>
    <TileMatrix>
    <ows:Identifier>11</ows:Identifier>
    <ScaleDenominator>272989.38673237007</ScaleDenominator>
    <TopLeftCorner>-2.0037508342787E7 2.0037508342787E7</TopLeftCorner> <TileWidth>256</TileWidth> <TileHeight>256</TileHeight>
    <MatrixWidth>573</MatrixWidth> <MatrixHeight>748</MatrixHeight>
    </TileMatrix>
    <TileMatrix>
    <ows:Identifier>12</ows:Identifier>
    <ScaleDenominator>136494.69336618503</ScaleDenominator>
    <TopLeftCorner>-2.0037508342787E7 2.0037508342787E7</TopLeftCorner> <TileWidth>256</TileWidth> <TileHeight>256</TileHeight>
    <MatrixWidth>1146</MatrixWidth> <MatrixHeight>1496</MatrixHeight>
    </TileMatrix>
    <TileMatrix>
    <ows:Identifier>13</ows:Identifier>
    <ScaleDenominator>68247.34668309252</ScaleDenominator>
    <TopLeftCorner>-2.0037508342787E7 2.0037508342787E7</TopLeftCorner> <TileWidth>256</TileWidth> <TileHeight>256</TileHeight>
    <MatrixWidth>2292</MatrixWidth> <MatrixHeight>2992</MatrixHeight>
    </TileMatrix>
    <TileMatrix>
    <ows:Identifier>14</ows:Identifier>
    <ScaleDenominator>34123.67334154626</ScaleDenominator>
    <TopLeftCorner>-2.0037508342787E7 2.0037508342787E7</TopLeftCorner> <TileWidth>256</TileWidth> <TileHeight>256</TileHeight>
    <MatrixWidth>4583</MatrixWidth> <MatrixHeight>5984</MatrixHeight>
    </TileMatrix>
    <TileMatrix>
    <ows:Identifier>15</ows:Identifier>
    <ScaleDenominator>17061.836671245605</ScaleDenominator>
    <TopLeftCorner>-2.0037508342787E7 2.0037508342787E7</TopLeftCorner> <TileWidth>256</TileWidth> <TileHeight>256</TileHeight>
    <MatrixWidth>9165</MatrixWidth> <MatrixHeight>11968</MatrixHeight>
    </TileMatrix>
    <TileMatrix>
    <ows:Identifier>16</ows:Identifier>
    <ScaleDenominator>8530.918335622802</ScaleDenominator>
    <TopLeftCorner>-2.0037508342787E7 2.0037508342787E7</TopLeftCorner> <TileWidth>256</TileWidth> <TileHeight>256</TileHeight>
    <MatrixWidth>18330</MatrixWidth> <MatrixHeight>23936</MatrixHeight>
    </TileMatrix>
    <TileMatrix>
    <ows:Identifier>17</ows:Identifier>
    <ScaleDenominator>4265.459167338929</ScaleDenominator>
    <TopLeftCorner>-2.0037508342787E7 2.0037508342787E7</TopLeftCorner> <TileWidth>256</TileWidth> <TileHeight>256</TileHeight>
    <MatrixWidth>36660</MatrixWidth> <MatrixHeight>47871</MatrixHeight>
    </TileMatrix>
    <TileMatrix>
    <ows:Identifier>18</ows:Identifier>
    <ScaleDenominator>2132.729584141936</ScaleDenominator>
    <TopLeftCorner>-2.0037508342787E7 2.0037508342787E7</TopLeftCorner> <TileWidth>256</TileWidth> <TileHeight>256</TileHeight>
    <MatrixWidth>73319</MatrixWidth> <MatrixHeight>95742</MatrixHeight>
    </TileMatrix>
    <TileMatrix>
    <ows:Identifier>19</ows:Identifier>
    <ScaleDenominator>1066.3647915984968</ScaleDenominator>
    <TopLeftCorner>-2.0037508342787E7 2.0037508342787E7</TopLeftCorner> <TileWidth>256</TileWidth> <TileHeight>256</TileHeight>
    <MatrixWidth>146638</MatrixWidth> <MatrixHeight>191484</MatrixHeight>
    </TileMatrix>
    </TileMatrixSet>
    <TileMatrixSet>
    <ows:Title>GoogleMapsCompatible</ows:Title>
    <ows:Abstract>the wellknown 'GoogleMapsCompatible' tile matrix set defined by OGC WMTS specification</ows:Abstract>
    <ows:Identifier>GoogleMapsCompatible</ows:Identifier>
    <ows:SupportedCRS>urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG:6.18.3:3857</ows:SupportedCRS>
    <WellKnownScaleSet>urn:ogc:def:wkss:OGC:1.0:GoogleMapsCompatible</WellKnownScaleSet>
    <TileMatrix>
    <ows:Identifier>0</ows:Identifier>
    <ScaleDenominator>559082264.0287178</ScaleDenominator>
    <TopLeftCorner>-20037508.34278925 20037508.34278925</TopLeftCorner>
    <TileWidth>256</TileWidth>
    <TileHeight>256</TileHeight>
    <MatrixWidth>1</MatrixWidth>
    <MatrixHeight>1</MatrixHeight>
    </TileMatrix>
    <TileMatrix>
    <ows:Identifier>1</ows:Identifier>
    <ScaleDenominator>279541132.0143589</ScaleDenominator>
    <TopLeftCorner>-20037508.34278925 20037508.34278925</TopLeftCorner>
    <TileWidth>256</TileWidth>
    <TileHeight>256</TileHeight>
    <MatrixWidth>2</MatrixWidth>
    <MatrixHeight>2</MatrixHeight>
    </TileMatrix>
    <TileMatrix>
    <ows:Identifier>2</ows:Identifier>
    <ScaleDenominator>139770566.0071794</ScaleDenominator>
    <TopLeftCorner>-20037508.34278925 20037508.34278925</TopLeftCorner>
    <TileWidth>256</TileWidth>
    <TileHeight>256</TileHeight>
    <MatrixWidth>4</MatrixWidth>
    <MatrixHeight>4</MatrixHeight>
    </TileMatrix>
    <TileMatrix>
    <ows:Identifier>3</ows:Identifier>
    <ScaleDenominator>69885283.00358972</ScaleDenominator>
    <TopLeftCorner>-20037508.34278925 20037508.34278925</TopLeftCorner>
    <TileWidth>256</TileWidth>
    <TileHeight>256</TileHeight>
    <MatrixWidth>8</MatrixWidth>
    <MatrixHeight>8</MatrixHeight>
    </TileMatrix>
    <TileMatrix>
    <ows:Identifier>4</ows:Identifier>
    <ScaleDenominator>34942641.50179486</ScaleDenominator>
    <TopLeftCorner>-20037508.34278925 20037508.34278925</TopLeftCorner>
    <TileWidth>256</TileWidth>
    <TileHeight>256</TileHeight>
    <MatrixWidth>16</MatrixWidth>
    <MatrixHeight>16</MatrixHeight>
    </TileMatrix>
    <TileMatrix>
    <ows:Identifier>5</ows:Identifier>
    <ScaleDenominator>17471320.75089743</ScaleDenominator>
    <TopLeftCorner>-20037508.34278925 20037508.34278925</TopLeftCorner>
    <TileWidth>256</TileWidth>
    <TileHeight>256</TileHeight>
    <MatrixWidth>32</MatrixWidth>
    <MatrixHeight>32</MatrixHeight>
    </TileMatrix>
    <TileMatrix>
    <ows:Identifier>6</ows:Identifier>
    <ScaleDenominator>8735660.375448715</ScaleDenominator>
    <TopLeftCorner>-20037508.34278925 20037508.34278925</TopLeftCorner>
    <TileWidth>256</TileWidth>
    <TileHeight>256</TileHeight>
    <MatrixWidth>64</MatrixWidth>
    <MatrixHeight>64</MatrixHeight>
    </TileMatrix>
    <TileMatrix>
    <ows:Identifier>7</ows:Identifier>
    <ScaleDenominator>4367830.187724357</ScaleDenominator>
    <TopLeftCorner>-20037508.34278925 20037508.34278925</TopLeftCorner>
    <TileWidth>256</TileWidth>
    <TileHeight>256</TileHeight>
    <MatrixWidth>128</MatrixWidth>
    <MatrixHeight>128</MatrixHeight>
    </TileMatrix>
    <TileMatrix>
    <ows:Identifier>8</ows:Identifier>
    <ScaleDenominator>2183915.093862179</ScaleDenominator>
    <TopLeftCorner>-20037508.34278925 20037508.34278925</TopLeftCorner>
    <TileWidth>256</TileWidth>
    <TileHeight>256</TileHeight>
    <MatrixWidth>256</MatrixWidth>
    <MatrixHeight>256</MatrixHeight>
    </TileMatrix>
    <TileMatrix>
    <ows:Identifier>9</ows:Identifier>
    <ScaleDenominator>1091957.546931089</ScaleDenominator>
    <TopLeftCorner>-20037508.34278925 20037508.34278925</TopLeftCorner>
    <TileWidth>256</TileWidth>
    <TileHeight>256</TileHeight>
    <MatrixWidth>512</MatrixWidth>
    <MatrixHeight>512</MatrixHeight>
    </TileMatrix>
    <TileMatrix>
    <ows:Identifier>10</ows:Identifier>
    <ScaleDenominator>545978.7734655447</ScaleDenominator>
    <TopLeftCorner>-20037508.34278925 20037508.34278925</TopLeftCorner>
    <TileWidth>256</TileWidth>
    <TileHeight>256</TileHeight>
    <MatrixWidth>1024</MatrixWidth>
    <MatrixHeight>1024</MatrixHeight>
    </TileMatrix>
    <TileMatrix>
    <ows:Identifier>11</ows:Identifier>
    <ScaleDenominator>272989.3867327723</ScaleDenominator>
    <TopLeftCorner>-20037508.34278925 20037508.34278925</TopLeftCorner>
    <TileWidth>256</TileWidth>
    <TileHeight>256</TileHeight>
    <MatrixWidth>2048</MatrixWidth>
    <MatrixHeight>2048</MatrixHeight>
    </TileMatrix>
    <TileMatrix>
    <ows:Identifier>12</ows:Identifier>
    <ScaleDenominator>136494.6933663862</ScaleDenominator>
    <TopLeftCorner>-20037508.34278925 20037508.34278925</TopLeftCorner>
    <TileWidth>256</TileWidth>
    <TileHeight>256</TileHeight>
    <MatrixWidth>4096</MatrixWidth>
    <MatrixHeight>4096</MatrixHeight>
    </TileMatrix>
    <TileMatrix>
    <ows:Identifier>13</ows:Identifier>
    <ScaleDenominator>68247.34668319309</ScaleDenominator>
    <TopLeftCorner>-20037508.34278925 20037508.34278925</TopLeftCorner>
    <TileWidth>256</TileWidth>
    <TileHeight>256</TileHeight>
    <MatrixWidth>8192</MatrixWidth>
    <MatrixHeight>8192</MatrixHeight>
    </TileMatrix>
    <TileMatrix>
    <ows:Identifier>14</ows:Identifier>
    <ScaleDenominator>34123.67334159654</ScaleDenominator>
    <TopLeftCorner>-20037508.34278925 20037508.34278925</TopLeftCorner>
    <TileWidth>256</TileWidth>
    <TileHeight>256</TileHeight>
    <MatrixWidth>16384</MatrixWidth>
    <MatrixHeight>16384</MatrixHeight>
    </TileMatrix>
    <TileMatrix>
    <ows:Identifier>15</ows:Identifier>
    <ScaleDenominator>17061.83667079827</ScaleDenominator>
    <TopLeftCorner>-20037508.34278925 20037508.34278925</TopLeftCorner>
    <TileWidth>256</TileWidth>
    <TileHeight>256</TileHeight>
    <MatrixWidth>32768</MatrixWidth>
    <MatrixHeight>32768</MatrixHeight>
    </TileMatrix>
    <TileMatrix>
    <ows:Identifier>16</ows:Identifier>
    <ScaleDenominator>8530.918335399136</ScaleDenominator>
    <TopLeftCorner>-20037508.34278925 20037508.34278925</TopLeftCorner>
    <TileWidth>256</TileWidth>
    <TileHeight>256</TileHeight>
    <MatrixWidth>65536</MatrixWidth>
    <MatrixHeight>65536</MatrixHeight>
    </TileMatrix>
    <TileMatrix>
    <ows:Identifier>17</ows:Identifier>
    <ScaleDenominator>4265.459167699568</ScaleDenominator>
    <TopLeftCorner>-20037508.34278925 20037508.34278925</TopLeftCorner>
    <TileWidth>256</TileWidth>
    <TileHeight>256</TileHeight>
    <MatrixWidth>131072</MatrixWidth>
    <MatrixHeight>131072</MatrixHeight>
    </TileMatrix>
    <TileMatrix>
    <ows:Identifier>18</ows:Identifier>
    <ScaleDenominator>2132.729583849784</ScaleDenominator>
    <TopLeftCorner>-20037508.34278925 20037508.34278925</TopLeftCorner>
    <TileWidth>256</TileWidth>
    <TileHeight>256</TileHeight>
    <MatrixWidth>262144</MatrixWidth>
    <MatrixHeight>262144</MatrixHeight>
    </TileMatrix>
    </TileMatrixSet>
    </Contents>
    <ServiceMetadataURL xlink:href="http://sampleserver6.arcgisonline.com/arcgis/rest/services/Toronto/ImageServer/WMTS/1.0.0/WMTSCapabilities.xml" /> </Capabilities>
```

This is the error in geoserver logs from Store creation onwards.  Layer preview results in unknownhostexception

> 2018-07-26 15:33:34,827 WARN [form.AjaxSubmitLink] - unexpected invocation of #onSubmit() on [AjaxSubmitLink [Component id = save]]
>   2018-07-26 15:33:34,827 WARN [form.AjaxSubmitLink] - unexpected invocation of #onAfterSubmit() on [AjaxSubmitLink [Component id = save]]
>   2018-07-26 15:33:37,675 INFO [geoserver.catalog] - Skipping WGS 84 / Pseudo-Mercator definition, it was not recognized by the referencing subsystem
>   2018-07-26 15:33:45,560 INFO [catalog.impl] - Layer cite:Toronto is missing the default style, assigning one automatically
>   2018-07-26 15:33:45,763 INFO [geoserver.gwc] - Saving GeoSeverTileLayer cite:Toronto
>   2018-07-26 15:33:48,093 WARN [geoserver.web] - Unable to find property: 'format.wms.application/vnd.google-earth.kml' for component:  [class=org.geoserver.web.demo.MapPreviewPage]. Locale: null, style: null
>   2018-07-26 15:33:48,093 WARN [geoserver.web] - Unable to find property: 'format.wms.rss' for component:  [class=org.geoserver.web.demo.MapPreviewPage]. Locale: null, style: null
>   2018-07-26 15:33:52,305 INFO [geoserver.wms] - 
>   Request: getServiceInfo
>   2018-07-26 15:33:53,430 INFO [geoserver.wms] - 
>   Request: getMap
>       Angle = 0.0
>       BaseUrl = http://localhost:8080/geoserver/
>       Bbox = SRSEnvelope[-79.45485558791692 : -79.31216718818739, 43.58252352397558 : 43.71178084047906]
>       BgColor = java.awt.Color[r=255,g=255,b=255]
>       Buffer = 0
>       CQLFilter = null
>       Crs = GEOGCS["WGS 84", 
>     DATUM["World Geodetic System 1984", 
>       SPHEROID["WGS 84", 6378137.0, 298.257223563, AUTHORITY["EPSG","7030"]], 
>       AUTHORITY["EPSG","6326"]], 
>     PRIMEM["Greenwich", 0.0, AUTHORITY["EPSG","8901"]], 
>     UNIT["degree", 0.017453292519943295], 
>     AXIS["Geodetic longitude", EAST], 
>     AXIS["Geodetic latitude", NORTH], 
>     AUTHORITY["EPSG","4326"]]
>       Elevation = []
>       Env = {}
>       Exceptions = SE_XML
>       FeatureId = null
>       FeatureVersion = null
>       Filter = null
>       Filters = null
>       Format = application/openlayers
>       FormatOptions = {}
>       Get = true
>       Height = 695
>       Interpolations = []
>       Layers = [org.geoserver.wms.MapLayerInfo@a332f658]
>       MaxFeatures = null
>       Palette = null
>       RawKvp = {REQUEST=GetMap, SRS=EPSG:4326, FORMAT=application/openlayers, BBOX=-79.45485558791692,43.58252352397558,-79.31216718818739,43.71178084047906, VERSION=1.1.0, STYLES=, SERVICE=WMS, WIDTH=768, HEIGHT=695, LAYERS=cite:Toronto}
>       RemoteOwsType = null
>       RemoteOwsURL = null
>       Request = GetMap
>       RequestCharset = UTF-8
>       ScaleMethod = null
>       Sld = null
>       SldBody = null
>       SldVersion = null
>       SortBy = null
>       SortByArrays = null
>       SRS = EPSG:4326
>       StartIndex = null
>       StyleBody = null
>       StyleFormat = sld
>       Styles = [StyleImpl[ name=raster]]
>       StyleUrl = null
>       StyleVersion = null
>       Tiled = false
>       TilesOrigin = null
>       Time = []
>       Transparent = false
>       ValidateSchema = false
>       Version = 1.1.0
>       ViewParams = null
>       Width = 768
>   2018-07-26 15:33:54,477 INFO [geoserver.wms] - 
>   Request: getServiceInfo
>   2018-07-26 15:34:07,180 ERROR [geotools.tile] - Failed to load image: http://sampleserver6.arcgisonline.com/arcgis/rest/services/Toronto/ImageServer/WMTS?request=getTile&tilematrixset=default028mm&TileRow=2991&service=WMTS&format=image%2Fpng&style=default&TileCol=2290&version=1.0.0&layer=Toronto&TileMatrix=13&
>   java.net.UnknownHostException: sampleserver6.arcgisonline.com
>       at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
>       at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
>       at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
>       at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
>       at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
>       at java.net.Socket.(Unknown Source)
>       at java.net.Socket.(Unknown Source)
>       at org.apache.commons.httpclient.protocol.DefaultProtocolSocketFactory.createSocket(DefaultProtocolSocketFactory.java:80)
>       at org.apache.commons.httpclient.protocol.DefaultProtocolSocketFactory.createSocket(DefaultProtocolSocketFactory.java:122)
>       at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpConnection.open(HttpConnection.java:707)
>       at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector.executeWithRetry(HttpMethodDirector.java:387)
>       at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector.executeMethod(HttpMethodDirector.java:171)
>       at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient.executeMethod(HttpClient.java:397)
>       at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient.executeMethod(HttpClient.java:323)
>       at org.geotools.data.wmts.client.WMTSTile.setupInputStream(WMTSTile.java:257)
>       at org.geotools.data.wmts.client.WMTSTile.doLoadImageTileImage(WMTSTile.java:232)
>       at org.geotools.data.wmts.client.WMTSTile.loadImageTileImage(WMTSTile.java:219)
>       at org.geotools.tile.Tile.getBufferedImage(Tile.java:163)
>       at org.geotools.map.WMTSCoverageReader.getTileImage(WMTSCoverageReader.java:365)
>       at org.geotools.map.WMTSCoverageReader.renderTile(WMTSCoverageReader.java:350)
>       at org.geotools.map.WMTSCoverageReader.renderTiles(WMTSCoverageReader.java:332)
>       at org.geotools.map.WMTSCoverageReader.getMap(WMTSCoverageReader.java:294)
>       at org.geotools.map.WMTSCoverageReader.read(WMTSCoverageReader.java:261)
>       at org.geotools.renderer.lite.gridcoverage2d.GridCoverageReaderHelper.readSingleCoverage(GridCoverageReaderHelper.java:637)
>       at org.geotools.renderer.lite.gridcoverage2d.GridCoverageReaderHelper.readCoverage(GridCoverageReaderHelper.java:213)
>       at org.geotools.renderer.lite.gridcoverage2d.GridCoverageRenderer.renderImage(GridCoverageRenderer.java:856)
>       at org.geotools.renderer.lite.gridcoverage2d.GridCoverageRenderer.renderImage(GridCoverageRenderer.java:819)
>       at org.geoserver.wms.map.RenderedImageMapOutputFormat.directRasterRender(RenderedImageMapOutputFormat.java:1037)
>       at org.geoserver.wms.map.RenderedImageMapOutputFormat.produceMap(RenderedImageMapOutputFormat.java:353)
>       at org.geoserver.wms.map.RenderedImageMapOutputFormat.produceMap(RenderedImageMapOutputFormat.java:269)
>       at org.geoserver.wms.map.RenderedImageMapOutputFormat.produceMap(RenderedImageMapOutputFormat.java:136)
>       at org.geoserver.wms.GetMap.executeInternal(GetMap.java:720)
>       at org.geoserver.wms.GetMap.run(GetMap.java:300)
>       at org.geoserver.wms.GetMap.run(GetMap.java:123)
>       at org.geoserver.wms.DefaultWebMapService.getMap(DefaultWebMapService.java:252)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
>       at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:333)
>       at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190)
>       at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
>       at org.geoserver.kml.WebMapServiceKmlInterceptor.invoke(WebMapServiceKmlInterceptor.java:38)
>       at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
>       at org.geoserver.gwc.wms.CacheSeedingWebMapService.invoke(CacheSeedingWebMapService.java:59)
>       at org.geoserver.gwc.wms.CacheSeedingWebMapService.invoke(CacheSeedingWebMapService.java:33)
>       at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
>       at org.geoserver.gwc.wms.CachingWebMapService.invoke(CachingWebMapService.java:72)
>       at org.geoserver.gwc.wms.CachingWebMapService.invoke(CachingWebMapService.java:52)
>       at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
>       at org.geoserver.ows.util.RequestObjectLogger.invoke(RequestObjectLogger.java:50)
>       at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
>       at [had to cut short to meet stackexchange reqmts]

Connecting to http://sampleserver6.arcgisonline.com/arcgis/rest/services/Toronto/ImageServer/WMTS?request=getTile&tilematrixset=default028mm&TileRow=2988&service=WMTS&format=image%2Fpng&style=default&TileCol=2291&version=1.0.0&layer=Toronto&TileMatrix=13&
works in the browser

Comment: I'm on my phone just now so I can't check but this question may help https://stackoverflow.com/q/5165126/439194 I'm not sure what version of apache http client we are using

Comment: Hi Ian - thanks for the prompt response - I'm a bit stuck - not sure what in that link is going to help me in so far as I cannot see which of the answers may be the one I'm looking for!  And not sure how to implement any of them as they largely appear code based.

Comment: I'm not sure if it will help other than to show it is a known issue for the version of the jar we used. Have a check to see which version we use and if an upgrade is required then please let us know via the JIRA issues page.

Comment: HI Ian - Did you get anywhere with this issue?